# How to make custom product attribute searchable in Shopware?

Tags: elasticsearch, shopware

I'm new in Shopware.
I understood how to add custom attribute but I can't find how to make it searchable. I got stuck.
It's necessary to add ISBN field to product and make it as searchable as Item number.
I saw [this](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/elasticsearch/#extend-product-search-query) and downloaded "ZIP package of this plugin" there, but everything I got from this is fatal error on search result page:

```
Facet ShopwarePlugins\SwagESProduct\SearchBundle\SalesFacet not supported in engine/Shopware/Bundle/SearchBundleDBAL/ProductNumberSearch.php on line 196

Stack trace:

#0 engine/Shopware/Bundle/SearchBundleDBAL/ProductNumberSearch.php(149): Shopware\Bundle\SearchBundleDBAL\ProductNumberSearch->getFacetHandler(Object(ShopwarePlugins\SwagESProduct\SearchBundle\SalesFacet))
#1 engine/Shopware/Bundle/SearchBundleDBAL/ProductNumberSearch.php(96): Shopware\Bundle\SearchBundleDBAL\ProductNumberSearch->createFacets(Object(Shopware\Bundle\SearchBundle\Criteria), Object(Shopware\Bundle\StoreFrontBundle\Struct\ShopContext))
#2 engine/Shopware/Bundle/SearchBundle/ProductSearch.php(65): Shopware\Bundle\SearchBundleDBAL\ProductNumberSearch->search(Object(Shopware\Bundle\SearchBundle\Criteria), Object(Shopware\Bundle\StoreFrontBundle\Struct\ShopContext))
#3 engine/Shopware/Controllers/Frontend/Search.php(76): Shopware\Bundle\SearchBundle\ProductSearch->search(Object(Shopware\Bundle\SearchBundle\Criteria), Object(Shopware\Bundle\StoreFrontBundle\Struct\ShopContext))
#4 engine/Library/Enlight/Controller/Action.php(159): Shopware_Controllers_Frontend_Search->defaultSearchAction()
#5 engine/Library/Enlight/Controller/Dispatcher/Default.php(523): Enlight_Controller_Action->dispatch('defaultSearchAc...')
#6 engine/Library/Enlight/Controller/Front.php(223): Enlight_Controller_Dispatcher_Default->dispatch(Object(Enlight_Controller_Request_RequestHttp), Object(Enlight_Controller_Response_ResponseHttp))
#7 engine/Shopware/Kernel.php(180): Enlight_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#8 vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpCache/HttpCache.php(491): Shopware\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#9 engine/Shopware/Components/HttpCache/AppCache.php(255): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpCache\HttpCache->forward(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), true, NULL)
#10 vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpCache/HttpCache.php(448): Shopware\Components\HttpCache\AppCache->forward(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), true)
#11 vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpCache/HttpCache.php(344): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpCache\HttpCache->fetch(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), true)
#12 engine/Shopware/Components/HttpCache/AppCache.php(178): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpCache\HttpCache->lookup(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), true)
#13 vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpCache/HttpCache.php(210): Shopware\Components\HttpCache\AppCache->lookup(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), true)
#14 engine/Shopware/Components/HttpCache/AppCache.php(114): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpCache\HttpCache->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#15 shopware.php(117): Shopware\Components\HttpCache\AppCache->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#16 {main}
```

Could everybody explain me please how to make product attribute searchable in Shopware and give normal working example?
Shopware version is 5.2.21 just in case.

Here's what I did: 
engine/Shopware/Plugins/Community/Frontend/IsbnSearch/Bootstrap.php:

```
    use ShopwarePlugins\IsbnSearch\SearchTermQueryBuilder\SearchTermQueryBuilder;
    /**
     * Class Shopware_Plugins_Frontend_IsbnSearch_Bootstrap
     */
    class Shopware_Plugins_Frontend_IsbnSearch_Bootstrap extends Shopware_Components_Plugin_Bootstrap
    {
        public function install()
        {
            $this->subscribeEvent(
                'Enlight_Bootstrap_AfterInitResource_shopware_search_es.search_term_query_builder',
                'decorateSearchTermQueryBuilder'
            );

            return true;
        }

        public function decorateSearchTermQueryBuilder()
        {
            $searchTermQueryBuilder = new SearchTermQueryBuilder(
                $this->get('shopware_search_es.search_term_query_builder')
            );
            Shopware()->Container()->set('shopware_search_es.search_term_query_builder', $searchTermQueryBuilder);
        }
    }
```

engine/Shopware/Plugins/Community/Frontend/IsbnSearch/SearchTermQueryBuilder/SearchTermQueryBuilder.php:

```
    namespace ShopwarePlugins\IsbnSearch\SearchTermQueryBuilder;

    use ONGR\ElasticsearchDSL\Query\BoolQuery;
    use ONGR\ElasticsearchDSL\Query\MultiMatchQuery;
    use Shopware\Bundle\SearchBundleES\SearchTermQueryBuilderInterface;
    use Shopware\Bundle\StoreFrontBundle\Struct\ShopContextInterface;

    class SearchTermQueryBuilder implements SearchTermQueryBuilderInterface
    {
        /**
         * @var SearchTermQueryBuilderInterface
         */
        private $decoratedQueryBuilder;

        /**
         * @param SearchTermQueryBuilderInterface $decoratedQueryBuilder
         */
        public function __construct(SearchTermQueryBuilderInterface $decoratedQueryBuilder)
        {
            $this->decoratedQueryBuilder = $decoratedQueryBuilder;
        }

        /**
         * @param ShopContextInterface $context
         * @param $term
         * @return BoolQuery
         */
        public function buildQuery(ShopContextInterface $context, $term)
        {
            $query = $this->decoratedQueryBuilder->buildQuery($context, $term);

            $matchQuery = new MultiMatchQuery(
                ['attributes.properties.swag_es_product.isbn'],
                $term
            );
            $query->add($matchQuery, BoolQuery::SHOULD);

            return $query;
        }
    }
```

I removed the rest of a code. Cause it just threw the error above. But looks like it's not enough.
Here's how attribute was created:

```
    $service = $this->container->get('shopware_attribute.crud_service');
    $service->update('s_articles_attributes', 'isbn', 'string');

    $service->update('s_articles_attributes', 'isbn', 'string', [
                'label' => 'ISBN',
                'supportText' => 'ISBN',
                'helpText' => 'ISBN',
                'translatable' => true,
                'displayInBackend' => true,
                'entity' => 'Shopware\Models\Article\Article',
                'position' => 140,
                'custom' => true,
                'unique' => true,
            ]);
```

Comment: This example related elastic search, are you sure you use elastic search on your project?

Comment: Dear, my main task there is to make custom attribute searchable.
And it doesn't matter, it will be elastic or not =)
Do you know how do this?

Comment: Example working well for Shopware 5.2.21. But example archive have not contain `SalesFacet`, so looks like code was modificated. You should show all your editions for I can help you.

Comment: "You should show all your editions for I can help you" What do you mean? The source code of a module?

Comment: Yes, archive with plugin doesn't contain this script: `ShopwarePlugins\SwagESProduct\SearchBundle\SalesFacet`

Comment: Did you find a solution for it, I'm stuck in the same plugin I want to implement